# Text in the div shows on top of the div instead middle

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

How to repair my code to show the text in the middle of div? Cause it's showing it on the top of the div...

```
#fixed-menu {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
      width: 100%;
    height: 38px;
    font-weight: light;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #0082c5; 
    border: 3px solid #0082c5;
}

#fixed-menu img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#fixed-menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#fixed-menu li { 
color: #fff;
display: inline; 
padding: 10px;
}
#fixed-menu a {
    padding-top: 3px;
    transition:all linear 0.20s;
    font-family: sans-serif;    
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;


}
#fixed-menu a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

I also tried to put there image, so to be aligned in the middle as in the #fixed-menu img, but it does not work, because when I did not have that #fixed-menu img, and I uploaded file in the div, the picture shows next to the text, aligned by the bottom of the text next to text , and when the vertical-align for image is set to middle, the picture is then showing of bottom...o.O How to repair it? here is Jfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wD5T9/68/
Thanks for answers

Comment: Your `CSS` does not reflect your `HTML` in your fiddle. `#fixed-menu` does not exist.

Comment: why? I see that menu without problems on fiddle

Comment: Ow i noticed that's the different fiddle damn

Answer (score 0):

The first try no additional code in a div and image

```css
#fixed-menu {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  font-weight: light;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #0082c5;
  border: 3px solid #0082c5;
}

#fixed-menu img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 25px;
}

#fixed-menu ul {
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#fixed-menu li {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}

#fixed-menu a {
  padding-top: 3px;
  transition: all linear 0.20s;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#fixed-menu a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

#searchWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#searchWrapper img {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='searchWrapper'>
  <input id='searchBox' style='width:250px; border:1px solid #cccccc; border-radius:7px 7px 7px 7px; padding:5px 28px 5px 10px; margin-top:14px; margin-left:50px;height:18px;' type='text' placeholder='Search' /><img src='http://www.q-park.ie/Portals/8/images/search-icon.png'
  />
</div>
```

Comment: "searchwrapper" div is not mine though,, it looks like the fiddle i pasted saved the old html and kept only my css... so the searchwrapper is not solution here